# How to avoid SWT table enlargement correctly?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a simple SWT program like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setMinimumSize(300, 300);

    // table
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    final GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gridData.heightHint = 0; // "hack"
    table.setLayoutData(gridData);

    // example data
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        final TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("item no." + i);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

**What I expect** - I want the table to completely fill out the shells space without changing it's size. (Screenshot 1 and 3)

**Problem** - If I add rows to the table, the table automatically gets resized (and so also the shell). (Screenshot 2)

**Workaround** - To avoid this behaviour I added the line `gridData.heightHint = 0;` to the code. But this seems like a hack to me.

**Question** - What would be the correct way to avoid the enlargement of the table (and the shell) when data is added?

Regards, winklerrr

#### Screenshot 1

Without data, table and shell don't get resized, correct behaviour, in both versions
[image: Empty table (correct)]

#### Screenshot 2

With data, table and shell are getting enlarged, wrong behaviour, only **without the hack**
[image: Full table (wrong)]

#### Screenshot 3

With data, table and shell don't get resized, scrollbar is added, correct behaviour, only **with the hack**
[image: Full table (correct)]

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your issue?

Comment: @Baz what are you missing?

Comment: It works fine here when I try it, but as the first answer says, did you call `shell.setSize()`? We'd know that if you post an MCVE.

Comment: I would say the heightHint is OK. You can specify a positive number to force the table to a fixed size.

Comment: @Baz I updated the post, I hope it's better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `shell.setSize(int width, int height)` at some point before adding data to the table?

Comment: It works if I add this call after `shell.pack()` (or even replace `shell.pack()` with this call). Calling it before adding data to the table doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

You usually expect the table to have a certain *logical* height, say 20 rows. At least that's an approach I often choose.

To achieve that, I compute the expected initial height in pixels like this and use it as a height hint.

```java
gridData.heightHint = table.getItemHeight() * 20;
```

To be more accurate, you would also want to add the table's trim.

Answer (score 1):

```
shell.setSize(int width, int height)
```

add this code after the data to your table.

Comment: If I add this before `shell.pack()` nothing changes. So it seems, that I need to add this after or even replace `shell.pack()` with it.